# How to use squid 3.5 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, squid

I'm trying to use squid proxy server in my lab but the video that are available on the youtube are old so kindly guide me install and configure Squid Proxy 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. And one more thing i want provide the internet to the clients how to do that using a server system (2 Ethernet port 1. Internet/IN by ISP 2. Internet/OUT by Server).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, configuring squid is fairly straight forward if you want a basic, untailored installation. Install it with `sudo apt install squid`. This will install squid, and create a default configuration file `/etc/squid/` named `squid.conf`. This probably has to be edited to suit your setup, including ACL rules for allowing access.

If you want to go beyond that, this is a fairly complex topic, as squid can do a lot of things, and what you need depends on what you want - only filtering, only caching, caching and filtering, caching of MS Windows updates, reverse proxy (i.e. acting as front end for a web server).

The file itself is fairly well commented, so you'll be able to set up an working configuration just by reading the configuration file if you are familiar with networking and how a proxy works. This is not something I'd suggest videos for. I'd suggest reading the [Squid documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/). It's very well documented, and google will give you tons of working examples for specific cases.

Note that caching is more difficult as of today, as more and more traffic is encrypted, and thus not cacheable. Notable exceptions are for instance Windows updates, and OS updates, where you can save significant amounts of bandwidth by caching - and they're distributed in clear text as the content is signed.

For sharing internet acccess, you can either use squid (to give www and ftp only) access, or you can do some kind of routing. The most common routing in residential and small corporate settings is NAT, where the router translates one external, public, address to many internal.

Other kind of routing is simply look up based on a routing table, and forwarding the packet to the next hop. This can be used within the same network, with private IP's, or externally with public IP's. This is in effect what's common for IPv6, and the public internet. Additionally the router can employ ACLs, Access Control Lists, to permit or deny traffic based on set criteria.

In short, this is a fairly complex topic, and I'm barely scratching the surface of it here - but giving a more complete answer requires more knowledge of what you are trying to do or achieve. In addition giving a step by step will likely not teach you a lot; you have to learn the basics of networking, and have a working understanding of how hosts on the internet talks to each other, and how packets are handled. A certain protocol knowledge of HTTP is also good, if you aim to set up a proxy.

So to get a better answer you have to be more specific as to what you want to achieve, and what knowledge level you have.